# C++11: How is boost::make_tuple different from std::make_tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple
(for convenience code is pasted)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

std::tuple<int, int> f() // this function returns multiple values
{
    int x = 5;
    return std::make_tuple(x, 7); // return {x,7}; in C++17
}

int main()
{
    // heterogeneous tuple construction
    int n = 1;
    auto t = std::make_tuple(10, "Test", 3.14, std::ref(n), n);
    n = 7;
    std::cout << "The value of t is "  << "("
              << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", "
              << std::get<2>(t) << ", " << std::get<3>(t) << ", "
              << std::get<4>(t) << ")\n";

    // function returning multiple values
    int a, b;
    std::tie(a, b) = f();
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.tuple

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  typedef boost::tuple<std::string, int, bool> animal;
  animal a = boost::make_tuple("cat", 4, true);
  a.get<0>() = "dog";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << '\n';
}
```

It would seem based on the documentation that boost::make_tuple and std::make_tuple are exactly interchangeable.

Are they really exactly interchangeable? In what circumstances are they not?

In the boost documentation it says that boost::tuple and std::tuple are the same in c++11

In the std documentation it says make_tuple returns a std::tuple.

So are there any nuances that I am missing?

Comment: I think C++11 pretty much just adopted boost::tuple. So it's not surprising they'd be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no functional difference.

`boost::tuple` was created almost two decades ago, and `std::tuple` was introduced to the core Standard Library in C++11, in 2011, only 6 years ago.

They're not "interchangable", for a given definition of the term "interchangable". You can't assign a `std::tuple<>` to a `boost::tuple<>` or vice-versa, because even if their implementation is the same, they still represent distinct objects.

However, because they are essentially the same, you can do a find→replace for `boost::tuple`→`std::tuple` and more-or-less arrive with identically behaving and performing code, and because dependency on the boost libraries is not something every programmer can have, it's almost universally recommended that any project which has access to >=C++11 prefer `std::tuple` in all cases.

## EDIT:

As pointed out by @Nir, there are a few syntactical differences between `boost::tuple` and `std::tuple`, notably involving the `get<>()` syntax, which is also a member function of `boost::tuple` and only a free function for `std::tuple`.

Comment: One very major difference between boost and std tuple, is that boost tuple has a member `get` function which is actually probably its most used method. In std `get` is only offered as a free function, so the refactoring you are suggesting would probably badly break most codebases.

Comment: "There's no functional difference." this is not quite true. `boost::tuple` functionality is more reach so you cannot expect everything will work with simple replacement. And your edit is not quite correct - boost provide both member and free function while std only free one.

Comment: @Slava "*`boost::tuple` functionality is more reach*" I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: boost provides both free function and member function for `get<N>`, std only provides free, so even OPs example would not compile with you suggested edit, boost also provides `operator<<` for tuple while `std` does not. There could be more.